# Cannot start Apache on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

While my apache was working the first days, it suddenly stopped and i cannot find the reason.

```
service apache2 status
```

gives:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-02-23 16:45:59 EET; 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8807 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8829 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Check the logs with: `journalctl -ex`

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun shutting down.
Φεβ 23 16:45:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
Φεβ 23 16:45:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Φεβ 23 16:45:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Φεβ 23 16:45:59 Sakis-Desktop sudo[8801]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop sudo[8880]:    sakis : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/sakis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop sudo[8880]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun shutting down.
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Φεβ 23 16:47:59 Sakis-Desktop systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

Tried also to check if the port 80 is taken, but it is not.
Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` that points to the reason? From the output above, it looks like something told Apache to shut down. The log should explain what.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately i am not getting any error in my logs.
Is there any log to check the actions per PID ?